# Automating copying files in bash

Tags: bash, terminal, copy

I have a list of files and directories (in a text file) that I need to copy to a slightly different path how can i do this with bash? example the list of files all look like this

```
html/app/design-old/[path-to-file-or-directory]
```

i want them all to be copied to

```
html/app/design/[same-path-to-file-or-directory]
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: no, can someone explain why this question was placed on hold and down-voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the list of paths in a file called `list.txt`,
one filename per line,
this should work:

```
source_dir=html/app/design-old
target_dir=html/app/design

while read path; do
    newpath=${path/$source_dir/$target_dir}
    target_basedir=$(dirname "$newpath")
    mkdir -p "$target_basedir"
    cp -r "$path" "$target_basedir/"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: `while read filename; do  
   cp -r "$source_dir/$filename" "$target_dir/${filename%/*}"; done < nothelp2.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
while read filename; do  
   cp -r "$source_dir/$filename" "$target_dir/${filename%/*}"; done < nothelp2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Is html in the root or the current directory? Assuming it's in the root and you only want to copy a file from the "default" directory...

```
mkdir /html/app/design
mkdir /html/app/design/frontend
mkdir /html/app/design/frontend/base
mkdir /html/app/design/frontend/base/default
cd /html/app/design-old/frontend/base/default
cp filename ../../../../design/frontend/base/default
```

if you want to copy a directory, change the last line to

```
cp directoryname ../../../../design/frontend/base/default -r
```

Notice the -r for dir copy.

Comment: I suggest to use `mkdir`'s option `-p`.